# Jquery Click a Link show a box and else close a box

Tags: jquery, click

Is there anything wrong this code. Tried and tested a hundred times.

```
<a href="#comment_magic" id="comment_magic_1" name="comment_magic_1" class="u">0 comments</a>
<div id="open_sesame_1" style="display:none" class="open_sesame_1">
test
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#comment_magic_1").click(
function () {
$("#open_sesame_1").slideDown();
}, function () {
$("#open_sesame_1").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by passing two functions as parameters to the click handler? .click() takes either no parameters, to invoke the handler, one parameter, to bind the handler, or two parameters, where the first is an array of eventdata and the second is the handler to pass it to.

Comment: Do you know about `slideToggle()`? I think that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) doesn´t take two event handlers.

> **.click( handler(eventObject) )**
>
> **handler(eventObject)** A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

You can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead.

```
$("#comment_magic_1").click(function() {
    $("#open_sesame_1").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information; I never realised it does not support two click handlers. Repped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$("#comment_magic_1").click(function() {
       $("#open_sesame_1").slideToggle();
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hxS3d/

Comment: Thanks. I also rather liked slideToggle and should have realized it would be better here as the link is one and it kills two birds with one stone. Everyone else repped.

Answer (score 1):

In case I get you right and you want the slideUp to trigger on second click, you cannot pass a second handler function to the click-binder. Instead you could use `slideToggle()` that will either show or hide the selection based on its current visibility.

Like:

```
$('#comment_magic_1').click(function(){
     $("#open_sesame_1").slideToggle();
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

You have given your div css `display none`, and then you are sliding it up and down. Since it is no where visible you don't see the action happening. In your jquery add css `display:block` onclick and then it will slide up and slidedown.

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6sz6V/3/